Export React as one inline HTML file
I am making one-page websites for particular service that accepts only single inline html files. I want to make these webpages as modularly as possible (to make many versions of them) and am thus using React to have ready components. I need to export the final React code to single inline static html-file. Images should be Base64 strings and css+javascript should be inline in the html.
The output should be:
dist
- index.html

How do I do this with React? Can I use Next.js or Vite?
I tried messing with Next.js export options in next.config.tsx and also tried couple of webpack plugins such as html-webpack-plugin with no success. I need some concrete advice on how to setup the export for React.

Instead of the html-webpack-plugin try to use the html-bundler-webpack-plugin.
Using this plugin, the entrypoint is HTML template, where you can directly define source JS/TS and SCSS files.
The plugin resolves source files of assets in HTML template and replaces them with inlined code in tags: <script> and <style>. For inlined images see: How to inline SVG, PNG images in HTML. Of cause, the plugin can save generated assets into separate files too.
For Example:
There is the HTML template for React:
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- relative path to favicon source file -->
    <link href="./favicon.png" rel="icon" />
    <!-- relative path to SCSS source file -->
    <link href="./style.scss" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!-- relative path to JS source file -->
    <script src="./App.ts"></script>
  </body>
</html>

Add to webpack config:
const HtmlBundlerPlugin = require('html-bundler-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new HtmlBundlerPlugin({
      entry: {
        index: 'src/index.html', // => dist/index.html
      },
      js: {
        // adds JavaScript to the DOM by injecting a `<script>` tag
        inline: true,
        // output filename of compiled JavaScript, used if inline is false
        filename: 'js/[name].[contenthash:8].js',
      },
      css: {
        // adds CSS to the DOM by injecting a `<style>` tag
        inline: true,
        // output filename of extracted CSS, used if inline is false
        filename: 'css/[name].[contenthash:8].css',
      },
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
        use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      // inline all assets: images, svg, fonts
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|webp|ico|svg|woff2?)$/i,
        type: 'asset/inline',
      },
    ],
  },
  performance: false, // disable warning max size
};

The generated HTML contains inlined CSS (including inlined images/fonts in CSS), inlined JS and inlined images into HTML:
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="data:image/png;base64,UklGRn..." rel="icon" />
    <style>
      body{background-image:url(data:image/webp;base64,UklGRn...);}...
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script>
      ... compiled JS Code...
    </script>
  </body>
</html>


Thanks! Is there a way to do this in Next.js or Vite though? Seems like the plugin is mainly for regular webpack and Vue but how could I set this up with a Next.js project for example? Tried to implement it to next.config.mjs in nextConfig : { webpack: ( ... ) => { ... } } but got error TypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation in my implementation. Vite works as well if there is not a way to do it with Next.js!
